# batch script to print previous and next lines of search string in a text file

Tags: windows, file, text, batch-file

I have a batch script which will print the entire line of search string into a text file.

```
for %%i in (log.txt) do (
FINDSTR /G:pattern.txt %%i >> output.txt
)
```

Example:
pattern.txt contains search string `ERROR` and below is the sample text in log.txt

```
2013-06-30 02:17:55,562 INFO   Service started
2013-06-30 02:17:55,578 INFO   Sending mail...
2013-06-30 02:17:55,578 DEBUG  Element value: 1
2013-06-30 02:17:55,578 ERROR  error occurred and message is ""
2013-06-30 02:17:55,578 DEBUG  bit version: 8
2013-06-30 02:17:55,578 INFO   Service stopped
```

The above batch script will print each line of text whenever it finds the string `ERROR` in log.txt So, the output.txt will look have lines like below

```
2013-06-30 02:17:55,578 ERROR  error occurred and message is ""
```

How can I print only previous and next lines of search string like below:

```
2013-06-30 02:17:55,578 DEBUG  Element value: 1
2013-06-30 02:17:55,578 DEBUG  bit version: 8
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Assemble the list of line numbers
set numbers=
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"error occurred" log.txt') do (
   set /A before=%%a-1, after=%%a+1
   set "numbers=!numbers!!before!: !after!: "
)
rem Search for the lines
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" log.txt ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do echo %%b) > output.txt
```

Comment: Added two more lines to generate output.txt                            `rem Search for the lines
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" log.txt ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do (
 if %%a == %before% >> output.txt echo %%b
 if %%a == %after% >> output.txt echo %%b
)`                                                                    Works fine for multiple search strings like "error occurred".        But only prints for the last occurrence. In real-time scenario, there will be multiple occurrences of search string. Is it possible to achieve without using third party tool?

Comment: The original code search for all occurrences of the string. Didn't you tested it? If you want to generate output.txt file, just enclose the last line this way: `(` original last line `) > output.txt`. I already modified the code above this way...

Comment: Awesome Aacini. Sorry. The code which I modified to generate output.txt file was searching only last occurrence. Your latest code is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

This uses a helper batch file called findrepl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

```
@echo off
set "var=searchterm"
type "file.txt"|findrepl "%var%" /o:-1:+1 |find /v "%var%"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /in "error" log.txt') do set /a found=%%a
if not defined found (echo "error" not found&goto:eof)
set /a line1=found-1
set /a line2=found+1
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /in "^" log.txt') do (
    if %%a==%line1% >>output.txt echo(%%b
    if %%a==%line2% >>output.txt echo(%%b
)
```

Comment: Throws error: "in was unexpected at this time" for the second  `for` loop  `for /f "tokens=1*delims=:"  in ('findstr /in "^" ATServer-webconsole.log') do (`

Comment: Endoro missed a `%%a`: `for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /in "^" log.txt') do (`

Comment: @Stephan Right. There are two more hurdles to cross.                       1. It's printing only for the last occurrence of the search string.   2. Not working for search string involving two or more words like `ISSUE DETECTED`. output.txt is not generated. Shows no error.

Comment: @Shrik sorry: made an edit. I would recommend to use `grep for Windows` for this, If you need such things more often.