# Batch script that finds textstring and prints the 3rd line above

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm using an existing script that looks for a textstring and prints the line above. I'm not able to reverse engineer the script.

1. The script runs the windows comand pnputil -e (see results below)

```
Published name :            oem41.inf
Driver package provider :   HID Global
Class :                     Smart card readers
Driver date and version :   12/13/2016 1.0.0.2
Signer name :               HID Global Corporation
```

2. Then it looks for '12/13/2016 1.0.0.2' and prints the line above. I need it to print the 3rd line above so the result would give 'oem41.inf'. At the moment the result is 'smart card readers'.

```
@echo off&color e
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo == 2016 Driver(s) Currently Installed ==
Echo.&Echo.

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('pnputil -e') do for /F "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do (
   if "%%b" equ "12/13/2016 1.0.0.2" (
      echo !line1prior!
   ) else (
      set "line1prior=%%b"
   )
)


Echo.&Echo.
echo == Press button to exit ==&pause>nul
exit
```

I tried reverse engineering the script in many ways but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing lines above search string in Windows Batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76874558/printing-lines-above-search-string-in-windows-batch-script)

Comment: As there are differences is the pnputil utility accross OS versions, and different, (better), ways of doing this rather that deleting a device driver based solely on a date and version, can you please tell us which Windows version(s) this is for so that we can assist you. Counting lines is not a robust way of doing this, _(especially if you don't wish to involve the creation, parsing, and subsequent deletion, of a temporary file)_.

Comment: I use pnputil in windows 10 & 11. There is a driver deployed across multiple machines install using an *.INF file. There is no easy way to delete the driver correctly as the driver package numbers are different on each machine (oem##.inf). The target driver shares the same manufacturer as other drivers on the machines which need retaining. I thought it would be better to target it via the version number and date. Then, the oem##.inf can be identified and the driver can be safely deleted using a script. The question here is simply regarding the identification of the oem##.inf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code adding the method suggested by T3RROR in his comment in a way that does not requires any temporary file.

**EDIT**: *Code modified to fix a subtle bug*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a "new line" (CR+LF) character pair:
for /F %%r in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set ^"\n=%%r^
%Don't remove this line%
^"

rem Set the value to search for
set "search=12/13/2016 1.0.0.2"

rem Show the 3rd line above the search one selected by FINDSTR command
pnputil -e > test.txt
findstr /R /C:".*!\n!.*!\n!.*!\n!.*%search%" test.txt | for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('more') do @for /F "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do @echo %%b
del test.txt
```

Note that the number of `.*!\n!` parts in the `findstr` command defines the number of lines above the searched one as described in the [Printing lines above search string in Windows Batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76886932/778560) suggested solution

Comment: Thank you Aacini, I have replaced each appearance of n with 3 after the findstr command however the published name is not being returned. The driver date and version is.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you... The code, as is, show the 3rd line above the search string as indicated in the `rem Show the 3rd line above the search one selected by FINDSTR command` comment, so you need to modify nothing in order to get the 3rd line above. Did you tested it?  I _never_ indicated you to replace the `n`!  **`:/`**

Comment: Apologies. When I try the batch script as it is, it doesn't return any results. I checked the driver is there and it is definitley there. For some reason I thought I needed to replace the n's with a 3 but ignore that. I'm using windows 10 if that helps?

Comment: This is strange. I completed several tests. When `findstr` directly process `pnputil` output via a pipe, the method fail. However, if pnputil output is first stored in a file, then findstr works correctly over such a file. I don't understand what is the difference. I modified the code accordingly; it should correctly works now

Comment: Many thanks Aacini. That works.