# Batch script that finds oem number of driver in windows command pnputil and deletes driver package

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have an existing script that I am unable to reverse engineer.

1. The script runs the windows comand pnputil -e (see results below)

```
Published name :            oem41.inf
Driver package provider :   HID Global
Class :                     Smart card readers
Driver date and version :   12/13/2016 1.0.0.2
Signer name :               HID Global Corporation
```

2. It then looks one line above to identify the .inf file
3. It then runs the command pnputil -f -d oem41.inf to delete the driver package.

I need to adapt the script so that it looks for '12/13/2016 1.0.02' and then identifies the 3rd line up which is oem41.inf so that the command pnputil -f -d oem41.inf can be sent.

Here is a copy of the existing code.

```
@echo off&color e
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


Echo.&Echo.

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('pnputil -e') do for /F "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do (
   if "%%b" equ "HID Global" (
        echo pnputil -f -d !line1prior!
    pnputil -f -d !line1prior!
   ) else (
      set "line1prior=%%b"
   )
)

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%c in ('pnputil -e') do for /F "tokens=*" %%d in ("%%c") do (
   if "%%d" equ "HID Global" (    
      echo pnputil -f -d !line1prior!
    pnputil -f -d !line1prior!
   ) else (
      set "line1prior=%%d"
   )
)

Echo.&Echo.
REM echo == Press button to exit ==&pause>nul
```

Attempted to reverse engineer existing script to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you really going to delete a driver based solely upon a matching date and version, irrespective of its class or provider?

Comment: It would also assist us if you were to tell us which Windows versions/editions this task is supposed to work on.

Comment: This is just [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77642498/batch-script-that-finds-textstring-and-prints-the-3rd-line-above) with a different title and slightly more content. Instead of asking the question a second time, please delete this and edit your first question.

Comment: Filtering the output of `pnputil` (changing `('pnputil -e')` to `('pnputil -e ^| findstr /b /c:"Published name :" /c:"Driver date and version :"'`) reduces the problem to a format compatible with the solution you already have ("the line above"). Consider Compo's advice to not make the date the only reason to delete a driver; you might get unlucky and render your system unusable.

Comment: I found two pairs of drivers with the same date/version and one triple of drivers with the same date/version on one of my systems. Three pairs, and a quadruple on another system. I strongly advise you to reconsider your approach.

Comment: I should also mention that `-e`, `-d`, and `-f` are all legacy options for `pnputil.exe` and Microsoft recommends that you instead use `/enum-drivers` `/delete-driver`, and `/force` nowadays.

Comment: Apologies. I'll add some context.

I use pnputil in windows 10 & 11. There is a driver deployed across multiple machines installed using an *.INF file.

There is no easy way to delete the driver correctly as the driver package numbers are different on each machine (oem##.inf). The target driver shares the same manufacturer as other drivers on the machines which need retaining. I thought it would be better to target the driver via the version number and date. Then, the oem##.inf can be identified and the driver can be safely deleted using the script. What do you suggest?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that yes, sometimes the same exact same driver will appear twice, or 3 times, all with different oem##.inf numbers. If that could be factored into the code that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is applicable to many similar situations

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%b IN ('pnputil -e') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=*delims= " %%e IN ("%%c") DO (
  rem criterion 1
  IF "%%b"=="Published name " (
   FOR  /F "delims==" %%e In ('set key 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%e="
   SET "key1=%%e"
  )
  rem criterion 2
  IF "%%b"=="Driver date and version " (
   SET "key2=%%e"
  )
  rem criterion n
  IF "%%b"=="Signer name " (
   IF "!key2!"=="09/26/2022 2.19.1.0" ECHO found !key1! with date/version !key2!
  )
 )
)
```

The outer loop assigns the key to `%%b` and data to `%%c` using `:` as a delimiter.

The inner loop removes leading spaces from `%%c` and assigns the remainder to `%%e`.

The first criterion clears the values assigned to variables whose names start `key`, then assigns the value found to `key1`. Note that the `key` part includes a terminal space since the first token of the line has a terminal space.

Any number of criteria can then be selected and assigned to variables `key?`

On the last keyname of the set, we can trigger actions based on the selection
criteria

As *Compo* & *Stephan* have both mentioned, your criteria probably need to be examined. The values indicated yielded three results on my system.

Comment: @Compo: Corrected. Likely I had duplicate-counting on my mind.

Comment: I was only joking, but thanks.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. This returns the driver package oem##.inf file and date & version. Can the script be adapted to delete the found driver package too? I've added some context to the comments in the original post.

Comment: @Magoo. I attempted to add a delete command to the end of the script however I don't think I'm doing it correctly. 

Assuming the identified inf file is oem11.inf, at the end of the script I am including the following:

echo pnputil /delete-driver !key1! /uninstall /force
pnputil /delete-driver !key1! /uninstall /force

however with the 1st line added, an oem##.inf file with a different number is being returned. What am i doing wrong here?